# Append DataSets (.ds) using UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, datastage

I'm currently working on DataStage IBM and here's my problem:
I have to get a n numbers of datasets that's going to be in a folder and I have to append them in one DataSet (.ds).

Since I don't know how many datasets I will have and neither they full name, I can't use a DataStage job to deal with them. All I know is they will have the same metadata (because they will be generated in the same job).

I think I have to use a Shell Cmd to append them but I'm not a UNIX guy.

Thank you for everyone who reads so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same job.  Specify Append mode (rather than Override) for the target Data Set; each time you run the job data will be added to the same Data Set.  Be careful not to inadvertently create duplicates by processing the same source data twice. Use parameters to specify the source.